# jpa incorrect syntax near 'limit'

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Can anybody please let me know, how can I retrieve Max value of specific column using spring data JPA.

I have been trying with findTopByOrderByIdDesc method which has been given in spring data JPA reference document, but I am getting "incorrect syntax near 'limit' exception.

the method signature from spring data JPA is

User findTopByOrderByAgeDesc();

and I am trying to use the same method signature, here this method is not expecting any argument to pass but according to the exception where can, I pass the limit.

even I try to change the method name as User findTop1ByOrderByIdDesc();

but this does work.
and I don't want to use @Query("some query")

```
public User getmaxSequence() {
        User user=new User();

        try {
            user=   userRepository.findTopByOrderByIdDesc();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

when I am running the code I am getting below exception stack trace.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1608)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:578)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:508)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:218)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:434)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 150 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set the Hibernate dialect in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a known bug in some versions of hibernate. I noticed it in 2.1.X an 2.2.X. Hibernate uses the "limit" keyword even when the dialect is set to a SQLServer dialect (e.g. SQLServer2012Dialect) which does not support that keyword. I was able to fix by overriding the managed version (2.1.214) with version 1.4:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.200</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).